# Traverse a generic list of KeyValue pair using Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, c#-3.0

I'm new to Lambda expressions so have been experimenting from an hour.

I have a generic list  - **`List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`**  basically holding a key

and a value pair. I'm looking to print the list items using lambda expressions. Can anyone

help me in translating the following foreach statement using Lambda expressions ?

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key.ToString() + " ----> " + kvp.Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad i was able to figure this out by myself :)

```
list.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.Key.ToString()  + " ----> " + item.Value.ToString()));
```

list: is the name of the list you want to traverse through

```
list<string> names=new list<string>{"name1","name2","name3"}; 
names.ForEach(name=>Console.WriteLine(name)); // write names to the console
console.Readline(); // wait on console until input
```

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulates LINQ expression by generic [Converter(TInput, TOutput)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y.aspx) delegate:

```
Converter<List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>, string> converter = (input) =>
    {
        return input.Select(i => i.Key + " --> " + i.Value)
                    .Aggregate((a, n) => a + Environment.NewLine + n);
    };
```

**Usage**:

```
string output = converter(items);
```

**Test data set**:

```
var items = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
    {
            new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "111"),
            new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "222"),
            new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "333"),
    };
```

**Output**:

```
1 --> 111
2 --> 222
3 --> 333
```

Comment: I used the below mentioned approach to print it. Anyways your solutions works too :)

Comment: Right, in case of list it would be the best and simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

Use Foreach method on your list

```
Array.ForEach(list.ToArray(), kvp=> Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key.ToString() 
+ " ----> " + kvp.Value.ToString()));
```